# Unable to load the requested file: helpers/_helper.php

Tags: codeigniter

I Can't understand this error, I have not load any helper then this error occurs, please help me to solve it.

MY CONTROLLER FILE

```
class User extends MY_Controller{

    public function index(){
    $this->load->view('public/form');
    }
}
```

Comment: which helper you are trying to load?

Comment: Your question does not contain the helper you are trying to load please be more clear.

Comment: It may be on the application/core/MY_Controller where the helper is loaded since your controller extends MY_Controller

Comment: please share you My_Controller code

Comment: <?php  

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

 
}

?>

Comment: without loading any helper why this error occurs.

Comment: You should learn how to edit your question.

Comment: my problem is just helper is not working any where in my project.

Comment: You have not specified what helper you are trying to load so we can not help you edit your question.

Comment: I am not seeing any error mentioned?? What was the error you got?

Comment: check your config file $config['enable_query_strings']  is  ENABLE OR NOT